# Как увеличить область клика item в Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Вопрос такой, как увеличить область клика `item` в `Toolbar`?
Я сделал `item` и установил свою иконку на него, но область клика у него стала маленькой и нужно кликать прямо в центр иконки, `ripple` эффекта соответственно тоже нет.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/my_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="My item" />
```

Хочу получить такой результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иконка это 3 точки? Можно дорисовать бесцветный круг к ним.

Comment: Иконка другая, это стандартные 3 точки.
Дорисовать круг к иконке? Но мне не только облость нужно увеличить, а и `ripple` поставить

Comment: Какую версию андроид вы используете? Ripple эффект по стандарту есть во всех Item, даже если вы используете свои иконки. А касательно области клика, врядли такое возможно, хотя может и возможно.

Comment: `minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27`

Comment: Рядом с моим item есть эти три точки, я поставил на них иконку и ripple тоже исчез.

Comment: @Colibri, по идее, если иконка у вас будет 24х24px для mdpi и 1.5х, 2х, 3х, 4х для остальных плотностей (если `*.png` используете) и будет иметь прозрачный фон то будет всё работать. Если вектор - просто делаете её 24x24dp и прозрачный фон.

Comment: Использую вектор 24х24 с прозрачным фоном

Comment: @Colibri, область клика можно увеличить, только если вы сделаете кастомный экшен бар. Что касается Ripple эффекта, то скорее всего дело в ваших иконках. Попробуйте использовать иконки из библиотеки.

Comment: На счет области вопрос отпал, на девайсе нормально все, это с эмулятором что то. На счет ripple, я менял вектор на png, пробовал использовать другие иконки, создавал vector assest из библиотеки, пробовал прописывать разные стили для тулбара, увы эффекта 0. Буду дальше пробовать что то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина по которой не было Ripple эффекта у `item`'a в вызове метода `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Я его вызывал для перерисовки меню, не знаю как он влияет на ripple, но убрав его проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

добавьте padding'и для item'а

для ripple эффекта вокруг item'а, добавте следущее:

`android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не помогло.
Причина в разметке или стилях, я сейчас пытаюсь найти. На другой activity добавил тот же item и все прекрасно работает.